Laravel Sum Main Table and Relation Table
column pups_born is in Main Table Delivery
column weaned_male and weaned_female in Relation table Weaning
on group by date_of_delivery in the main table I want result of sum pups_born,weaned_male and weaned_female
Delivery::with(['weaning' => function ($q) {
             $q->selectRaw('SUM(weaned_male) as total_weaned_male, SUM(weaned_female) as total_weaned_female');
    }])->selectRaw('*, sum(pups_born) as total_pups_born')->groupBy('date_of_delivery')->orderBy('date_of_delivery','desc')->get()

How to get Sum of Relation table along with the sum of main table?

You can perform aggregate queries on relations. See https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

What does your current query return ?

This solution is not even going to work, the reason is you need to know how laravel relation works and how eloquent detect which record belongs to which parent.
The laravel relations are detected by local key and the foreign key and can be explicitly set in model.
But in selectRaw of relation you ignored the foreign key.
The solution is using join, and query will be something like this:
Delivery::query()
    ->selectRaw('SUM(weaned_male) as total_weaned_male, SUM(weaned_female) as total_weaned_female, sum(pups_born) as total_pups_born')
    ->join('weanings', 'deliveries.weaning_id', '=', 'weanings.id')
    ->groupBy('date_of_delivery')
    ->get();

The columns and filtering can be different based on your need and you may want to use left join or change the query.
